Custom scrollbar movement restriction
I have created a custom code carousel with a custom scrollbar, navigation dots and buttons that is working properly when I navigate with Next/Prev Buttons. The problem is that I need to restrict the movement of the scrollbar because now is scrolling freely, everytime I drag the scrollbar everything stops working because the scrollbar stops in an indeterminate point. I'm struggling with this behaviour.
I need that, if I drag the scrollbar to the right, the next button function should be executed and the scrollbar should stop in the correct position and if I drag to the left the scrollbar should execute the Prev button function and should update the postion. Maybe someone could lend a hand.
I have created this codepen to check the full example:
https://codepen.io/pixelmary/pen/PovBZZz
let flag_mouseDown = false;
let oldMousePosition = 0;
let oldAnchorPosition = 0;
scrollBarContainer.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    if (e.target.nodeName === 'DIV') {
        var distance = e.clientX - sliderViewbox.offsetLeft - anchor.offsetWidth / 2;
        if (distance < 0) {
            distance = 0;
        } else if (distance + anchor.offsetWidth > containerWidth) {
            distance = containerWidth - anchor.offsetWidth;
        }
        anchor.style.left = distance + 'px';
        moveContent();
    } else if (e.target.nodeName === 'SPAN') {
        flag_mouseDown = true;
        oldMousePosition = e.clientX;
        oldAnchorPosition = anchor.offsetLeft;
    }
});

scrollBarContainer.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
    flag_mouseDown = false;
    oldMousePosition = e.clientX;
    oldAnchorPosition = anchor.offsetLeft;
    snapToNearestSlide();
});

scrollBarContainer.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    if (!flag_mouseDown) {
        return;
    }

    let distance = e.clientX - oldMousePosition;
    let newPosition = oldAnchorPosition + distance;

    if (newPosition < 0) {
        newPosition = 0;
    } else if (newPosition + anchor.offsetWidth > containerWidth) {
        newPosition = containerWidth - anchor.offsetWidth;
    }

    anchor.style.left = newPosition + 'px';
    moveContent();
});

const moveContent = function() {
    let position = anchor.offsetLeft / (containerWidth - anchor.offsetWidth);
    let newPosition = (0 - position * (contentWidth - containerWidth)) + 'px';
    for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
        content[i].style.marginLeft = newPosition;
    }
};



if I drag the scrollbar [...] the scrollbar should stop in the correct position - can you clarify? As a side note, are there not enough carousel libraries out there that would achieve what you want? Also, if you already have previous + next buttons as well as indicators, why would you need the scrollbar as well?

I'm not allowed to use external code in this project and the scrollbar is a desired component.

Why not? Is this a homework question?

Finally I've achieved the desired result simulating a drag over that anchor element. The result has been updated in the codepen. Have a nice day!

That is absolutely terrible in terms of UX... Side note : if you are going to accept your own answer, please provide the relevant code in the answer instead of referring to a link in your question that might become unavailable at any time. Or even better, delete both question and answer.
